# Energy of EM Fields in terms of Potentials

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential, atomic-physics

In reading the paper *On the nature of the Hamiltonian for the interaction of radiation with atoms and molecules: (e/mc)p⋅A,−μ⋅E, and all that* by E. A. Power, and T. Thirunamachandran (*AJP*, 1978), I came across the following passage:

> The $(e/mc) \mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{A}$ Hamiltonian for a coupled system of field and nonrelativistic electrons arises naturally from the conventional Lagrangian,
>   $$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m \sum_\alpha \dot{\mathbf{q}}_\alpha - V(\mathbf{q}) + \frac{1}{8\pi} \int \frac{\dot{\mathbf{A}}^2}{c^2} - (\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{A})^2\,dV - \frac{e}{c}\sum_\alpha \dot{\mathbf{q}}_\alpha \cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q}_\alpha). $$

(As a note, I believe this is in the Coulomb gauge, $\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$.)

The bit that confuses me is the third term, containing the integral. I would have supposed this to be the field energy, coming from the integral $$ \int \epsilon_0\mathbf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0}\mathbf{B}^2\,dV. $$ But if I put in the expression $\mathbf{E} = -\dot{\mathbf{A}} - \mathbf{\nabla}\phi$ for the electric field, I get some extra terms that I'm not convinced go to zero, namely $$ \int 2\dot{\mathbf{A}} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla}\phi + (\mathbf{\nabla}\phi)^2\,dV. $$ The minus sign in between the two terms of the third term's integral also confuses me.

Could someone work out the field energy (or energy density) in terms of the scalar and vector potential, perhaps showing me that these terms go to zero, or otherwise what I'm missing? Alternately, is there good reason to suppose, in the context of atom-light interactions, that $\phi=0$?

EDIT:

It turns out that you can effectively gauge-transform away the scalar potential while still keeping the Coulomb gauge. Perhaps that's the reason for these terms disappearing. I'm still very unsure about the minus sign in the integral, however, so perhaps a more in-depth derivation is still needed.